# pyside issue - pyside pyside [local] idle

Tags: postgresql, memory-leaks, pyside

I have a program use Pyside and Django's ORM to combine PostgreSQL.
When running the program for a few hours,  the system monitor(htop) had serval idle
" postgres: pyside pysde [local] idle"

**Have anyone give the suggestions?**

Comment: What does the program do?  If the program spends long periods doing internal computations or waiting for user input, then leaving the database connection idle while it does so does not indicate a problem.  If there is no problem, there is no need for a solution.

Comment: I write a sample to receive streaming as well as create and update to the database if motion.